# 2020 google nest thermistat and no C wire for floor boiler heat

Tags: nest

I think I have read all and still an issue.  I purchased a 2020 google nest wifi thermistat for my floor boiler in the basement (it only has R, W, Y, C, G and OB). The existing only has two connections a W and R as just for heat. The new requires a C.   I tried a 24 volt transformer hooked up to the R and C wire, disconnected the current R wire, and W.  This configuration worked to run the thermistat but did not operate the boiler when above room temp.   I did try one leg of the transformer to C and keep the R and W.  This showed no power on the nest.  I did see someone have the red and transformer wire both in R.  I am concerned this may not be best for the Navien boiler. Any advise would be appreciated.
Best regards,
GE

Comment: Are there any spare wires in your thermostat cable? How workable would it be to run new thermostat cable between thermostat and furnace?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your boiler, and of the wiring diagram on your boiler please, or a make/model or manual for your boiler for that matter?